# manually rendering ember component into html

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to manually render an ember component into html ?

for example, I want to add a custom template for a select2 option, which I have a component that renders it. the select2 components takes an html code as the "format".

I tried manually creating the component:

> I have the user component, and I want to use its 'html output':
>   App.userComponent.create({email:"manu@gmail.com", displayName:"manu",
>   size:"40", round:"true"})

But I can't fetch its html. How can I be sure that it is getting rendered ? or at least, is it possible to ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use a plain Handlebars helper and pass the data into it? It will return an html string.

Comment: I need to send the 'html' to a select2 js plugin, as the format of each line. this is calculated in runtime, and it is not a handlebars rendered template where I can use an handlebars helper.